# Query regarding pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  typedef struct node{
     int data;
     node* left;
     node* right;
   } nodeptr;
  nodeptr *root, *curr, *temp;
}
```

Does `nodeptr *root` and `nodeptr* root` represent the same thing?

Comment: One question per question please. Otherwise there's no value for future research.

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes. 3. Elaborate on _"it did not worked"_

Comment: Your second example misses a `;` after the struct declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the both codes represents the same thing ?

They almost represent the same thing, except that the first one defines `nodeptr` as a `typedef`ed name.

> Is int* a and int *a represents the same thing?

Yes.

> For the First code when i declared: `queue < nodeptr >q` it worked but for the second code when i declared in code: `queue < node >q` it did not worked. why?

`queue<nodeptr> q` is the same as `queue<node*> q`. Hence the comparison is not appropriate.

You should be able to use `queue<node>` if you use C++11. See it working at http://ideone.com/tkij08.

Comment: About local structs, that has been OK since C++11.

Answer (score 0):

int* a; and int *a; are the same. The white space here for pointers is perfectly fine and doesn't change any meaning.

queue node q should work. But perhaps ask that in a different question with more detail. I've attached some working code that does get `queue<node> q;` working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
   struct node
   {
     int data;
     node  *left;
     node  *right;
   };

int main()
{
   node *root, *curr, *temp;
   queue<node> q;
}
```

Comment: _"queue node q should work"_ ??? Show the code that _should work_ actually.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give working code.

Answer (score 0):

For your second Question, I would just say that either you write `int* a` or `int *a`, it is one and the same thing.

```
int* a;
int *a;
int * a;
```

All are same where a is a pointer to of type int, infact `int*a;` is a also same...

Comment: There's already a duplicate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Almost. Both define a `struct node`, but the first also defines a type for a pointer to `struct node` called `nodeptr`.
2. Nope, they are exactly the same thing. The whitespace, or lack thereof, does not matter.
3. Because in the first case you declare a queue of pointers to type node, while in the second you declare a queue of objects of type node. `queue` presumably makes an additional demand on its contents that `node` does not fulfill. Without seeing the source of `queue` it is hard to guess what that might be, but perhaps it needs a comparison-operator of some sort to be defined. If you want to know more you should really post example source and the error messages you get, and not just state 'it doesn't work'.